# Putting an Adview above Viewpager tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, adview

Hi I know how to integrate an `Adview` in my `Fragment` and also in my `Activity`. but can someone help me in placing the `Adview` above the `ViewPager tabs`..??
I need my `Adview` to be to be place above the tabs which are creating using the `Viewpager` and Implementing a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
Any help will be acknowledge.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the adview layout below the viewpager in xml. This will ensure adview comes on top of the viewpager

EDIT:

```
<NavigationDrawer>

  <RelativeLayout>   
     <ViewPager/>   
     <AdView/> 
  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView/> //Your navigationDrawer view
```

Comment: Well I tried, but it fails, as I am also having a Navigation drawer along with the viewpager in my base FragmentActivity.

Comment: You can place the viewpager in another relative layout and then add the adview as the second child of the relativeLayout check the edit

Comment: Let me check that mate, and if it works I am sure you are going to cross the 825 rating points... Thanks in advance...

Comment: It didn't worked, still the adview remains below the ViewPager based Action bar Implemented by using FragmentPagerAdapter. Could you please help for the same.